# Sqlite query returning 0 even if the value is null

Tags: android, sqlite

Following is the query I use to fetch an int value corresponding to a particular field in my sqlite db table.

```
"SELECT conn_status FROM profiles WHERE devID = '" + id+"'"
```

If there is no value saved for 'conn_status' corresponding to the devID provided, then the existing value in the table would be null. I retrieve the data from java as shown:

```
c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("conn_status"))
```

The problem here is, with the given query , c.getInt returns 0 even if the value existing in the field is null. How can I modify this query such that, it returns a different value instead of 0, say 5, if the value is null.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the `isNull()` function. Here's an example:

```
static int getInt(String columnName)
{
    if(c.isNull(c.getColumnIndex(columnName)))
        return -1;
    return c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(columnName));
}
```

Comment: Better practice return Integer not primitive int and return null not -1 and control errors in model.

Answer (score 16):

In SQLite, you can use the [`IFNULL`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull) function to replace `NULL` values:

```
SELECT IFNULL(conn_status, 5) FROM profiles WHERE devID = ?
```

Answer (score 3):

`int` in Java is a primitive datatype and cannot be `null`. Hence, if there is no value returned by your getInt, you get 0.
The Integer object may be null so you may want to consider using Integer instead of int if your logic requires you to check for nulls instead of 0's

Answer (score 2):

As you want any different value like 5 if column having null value then try following code.

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT conn_status FROM profiles WHERE devID = '" + id+"'");

    if(c.getCount>0){
    int number = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(conn_status));
    return number;
    }else{
    return 5;
    }
```

if cursor.getCount() return something means query work and database not having null value. If return opposite means query not work and databse having null value for respective query. So try it once.

Answer (score 0):

In Android use Integer object not int primitive, Integer is nullable, primitive int cause exception. In Model verify if value is null or process the content.

```
/**
 * Return real integer of value or null
 * @param column_name Name of column in result
 */
public Integer getInt(String column_name){
    try{
        if(cursor.isNull(cursor.getColumnIndex(column_name)))
            return null;
        return cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(column_name));
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("sqlite_exception", "column " + column_name + " not exists. " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tell if the column is null by calling getType().

```
Integer locationInfoId;

if (cursor.getType(columnIndex) == Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_NULL){
    locationInfoId = null;
} else {
    locationInfoId = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
}

columnIndex++;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a supposedly *`NULL`* value returning `0` in a `c.getInt(index)` call.

It turns out that my database had *a text value of* `null`.  That is, instead of a 0 byte value of *`NULL`*, there were 4 characters `'n' 'u' 'l' 'l'`.  This is confusing because `null` looks correct.  I didn't catch it until I checked the DB with a SQLite DB Browser.

When I replaced those text values, things worked as expected.

I know this is an old question, but hopefully this will save someone else some troubleshooting time.